# syntax error when calling PERFORM on a stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

not sure why but I am getting a syntax error as follows :

```
perform myProc('Expires in:','0');

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "perform"
```

not sure why this is happening, but here is my procedure if that makes any shred of difference?

```
create or replace procedure myProc(colkey varchar, colvalue varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
old varchar(250);
keyId bigint;

begin

select @keyid= id
from conkey
where conkey.key like colkey
limit 1;



if not exists (select * from ConValu where conkeyId= @keyid and appId is null) THEN 

else 

select @old_value_for_update = value 
from ConValu
where conkeyId= @conkeyId and appId is null
limit 1; 

update ConValu  set Value = colvalue where ConkeyId= @conkeyID and appId is null;

end if;

end; $$
```

Comment: I'd rather expect the syntax error come from the keyword `insert`…

Comment: changed the keyword and this is still occuring

Comment: `select @keyid= id` doesn't look like plpgsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SQL statement `PERFORM`. You have to use `CALL` to invoke a procedure.